# Close all tabs in TabPane

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I have this code this is very basic and it's used to close all tabs in a TabPane.

```
MenuItem item4 = new MenuItem("Close All Tabs");
    item4.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("Close All Tabs");
            int ee = tabPane.getTabs().size();
            tabPane.getTabs().remove(0, ee);
        }
    });
```

I want to optimize this part of the code:

```
        int ee = tabPane.getTabs().size();
        tabPane.getTabs().remove(0, ee);
```

Is there any other clear and optimized solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe

```
tabPane.getTabs().clear();
```